# Split email string from custom field before it is echoed on page - using PHP

Tags: php

I'm used to using javascript to scramble emails but I just realised my email address on my wordpress system will echo as a full string. Therefor javascript can't help me this time.

I use javascript to break email addresses but I always manually split the email string.

See below my custom field php from wordpress which echos a email address.

```
<?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true) )

    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true);

?>
```

My question is it possible to split get_post_meta before it's actually echoed on the page? but then echo it in bits... like an array.

This is what I normally use below, so if it is possible to split the above get_post_meta?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
// spam protected email
emailE=('david@' + 'example.com')
document.write('<a title="E-mail David" href="mailto:' + emailE + '">' + emailE + '</a>')
 //-->
</script>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true) ) { ?>

<?php 

        $email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true);
        $emailSpam = explode("@", $email);

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- 
        // spam protected email
        emailE=('<?php echo $emailSpam[0]; ?>' + '@' + '<?php echo $emailSpam[1]; ?>')
        document.write('<a class="exhibitor-links-icon-email" title="Click here to E-mail <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" href="mailto:' + emailE + '" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/x.gif" alt="" /></a>')
        //-->
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested: (Might be off by +1 char)

```
$emailBeginning = substr(0, strrchr($email, '@')); 
$emailEnd = substr(strrchr($email, '@'), strlen($email));
```

References (For the future) :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: Thanks for the references. I just figured it out using explode, I have posted working code above.

Comment: lol, i though that was the broken code. You should probably close the question, so people dont get confused

Comment: Yeh that is broken code. But my error was not in my explode php, it was other stuff. But yeh I'll close it now.